# tabBarOnPress Not Available in React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm using React Navigation v5 with `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` and my tabs look something like this.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component{SettingsScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

I want to open screens on **Home** & **Settings** tab but on the **Modal** Tab, I would like to **open an modal** and for that, with React Navigation v4, it is possible using `tabBarOnPress` which will run the callback but that is not available in React Navigation v5, is there any alternative for `tabBarOnPress` with React Navigation v5?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

You need to use `tabPress` event:

```js
<Tabs.Screen
  name="Modal"
  component={ModalScreen}
  listeners={{
    tabPress: e => {
      // Prevent default action
      e.preventDefault();
    },
  }}
/>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#events

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events#listeners-prop-on-screen

Comment: This is not recognized for me? tabPress is not available. Could it be, that it does not work with createNativeStackNavigator ?